# Xampp- Can't acess phpmyadmin ( Access forbidden!)

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Basically this error started to appear when trying to access phpmyadmin:

[image]

And after some research , i already edit the **httpd-xampp.conf**

```html
    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
          Require all granted 
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
```

And still having the same problem. So i changed the **httpd.conf**

```html
<IfModule dir_module>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>
```

Actually that worked but right now my phpmyadmin appear like that :

[image]

So right now i dont any idea what need to be done , and what is going on.

My logs are:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The directory list doesn't appear to show all files.  There should be an **index.php**.  That is what gets executed.  If the file is present, then **PHP** is not running.

The solution, therefore, is to **reinstall** xampp.

Comment: When i run xampp, if i go for example , localhost/mywebsite , php is working fine. Only in phpmyadmin the php doesn't work. that's normal? should i reinstall xampp?

Comment: Pedro, if the index.php is missing then you should definitely reinstall it.